# iOS 6 loading contacts ABAddressBookRef too slow

Tags: ios

I have an application that previously fine on the previos iOS 5, with no authorisation accessing on contacts. On iOS lower than 6 the contacts loads so fast even though I have 600 in my Address book but when I upgrade my device to iOS 6, I recode my code to check/ask authorisation and still its iOS 4, 5 compatible.
Here is the code:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef;

if ([self isABAddressBookCreateWithOptionsAvailable]) {
    CFErrorRef error = nil;
    addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,&error);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (error) {

            } else if (!granted) {

            } else {
                NSLog(@"granted");
                [self getAddressBookContacts];
            }
        });
    });
} else {
    [self getAddressBookContacts];
}
```

The problem now is on iOS 6 the address book now loads slower than lower iOS, anybody knows what is happening why it made too slow or what should be done to boost its speed in loading contacts?

Comment: What's the getAddressBookContacts function like?

Comment: it the part of this function that gets the contact. Like
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate();
    
    CFArrayRef contactsList = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef); 
    CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFArrayGetCount(contactsList), contactsList);
    CFArraySortValues(peopleMutable, CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable)), (CFComparatorFunction) ABPersonComparePeopleByName, (void*) ABPersonGetSortOrdering());
    CFIndex personCount = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBookRef);

Comment: In ios6 they integrated facebook contacts, this might be why. I think also, you can literally step over each line and try to see which line takes the longest. It could also be the sorting CFArraySortValues(peopleMutable, CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable))

Comment: I have no problem with sorting coz I'm doing it after all is fetch and with a button. It might be that facebook contacts added on address book but it shouldn't be a problem, on lower iOS i have tried loading 600 contacts with no time. The loading only appears in iPhone 5 iOS 6.